WebGPU: Changing the output format to non-float types, possible?
For rendering to <canvas>, it seems that navigator.getPreferredCanvasFormat() is the only way to get a valid format.
As per the docs, it will always return either rgba8unorm or bgra8unorm, both f32 types. If I try to set the format to anything other than those, e.g. to rgba8uint, I get GPUCanvasContext.getCurrentTexture: Canvas not configured on render.
Yet the documentation implies that other formats are possible, by stating that

if you don't use the preferred format when configuring the canvas
context, you may incur additional overhead, such as additional texture
copies, depending on the platform.

Just seems inefficient, even if the final render step happens on GPU anyway. Instead of 1 byte per channel (4B per pixel), have to use 4B per channel =  4x4-byte floats = 16B per pixel. Wasteful?
Happy to accept the texture-conversion hit if I can reduce the bandwidth cost.
Am I missing something here? Is this possible?

You can render to non-canvas textures that you instantiate yourself.
const nonScreenTexture = device.createTexture({});

These are textures that are not intended to being drawn directly to the screen.
If you use the TypeScript types (@webgpu/types) and look at the list of GPUTextureFormat formats, you will see that there are a lot of options. If you use extensions, there are even more, for some lossy-compression game industry formats.
The two formats supported by canvas currently are rgba8unorm and bgra8unorm. These are the SDR formats that will be sent to the Vulkan/DirectX/Metal back-end, to be composited with whatever else the OS needs to draw, and put on the screen. The one format (rgba) is common for handheld devices. The other format (bgra) is common for desktops / laptops. If you give the right device the right format, there are no extra copies. If you give it the wrong format, it will swap it to the right format. ...even if it supported more formats, by the time you submit it, and WebGPU submits it to Vulkan/DX/Metal, it will have copied it and converted it to one of these formats.
There's no saving of space here, because if you are talking about the format of the canvas texture, it's not something you get to touch or control. The browser internals and the computer's graphics drivers do. In order to support space saving, you'd be talking about your own Chrome build, with custom Dawn / ANGLE forks, to save DX/Vulkan the bits on an SDR draw call...
but they're working on adding wide-gamut and HDR support to WebGPU (they're already arriving in 2D canvas and CSS). This monitor in front of me is 12bpp, HDR, does, like, 98% DCI-P3 and a huge chunk of BT2020, with a low error. For WebGPU to perform like desktop GPU-enabled applications (not just narrow-gamut SDR), it needs to deal in more bits per pixel, and not fewer. You end up with things like DXGI_FORMAT_R11G11B10, which might still be 32-bits, but clearly, is not broken up the same way, at all.

Buried among the trivia, your comment about "what I do not get to control" is useful. However, it still leaves me with the (code) question of how that implicit texture conversion can take place, since I get an error thrown on submitting the wrong texture format. I would expect WebGPU to accept that submission, and to incur the overhead as stated in the docs. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong.

Yes. The question is "what are you actually trying to accomplish"? If you are just trying to get images to show up on the canvas, on the screen, then don't try to fix what WebGPU does. It does what it does. If you want to avoid extra buffer copies, use getPreferredCanvasFormat. If you are trying to get data to save to a file or whatever, use a texture instance, and not the canvas context. If it's an intermediary render step, you can use a different format, and then composite to bgra or rgba at the end. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

"However, it still leaves me with the (code) question of how that implicit texture conversion can take place, since I get an error thrown on submitting the wrong texture format." Maybe this helps: there are almost no implicit steps in WebGPU. This one is done as a service if you submit the wrong framebuffer type for the OS/device. It's not a "convert literally anything to valid framebuffer" step. If you want to composite, it's a separate pass, sampling the texture onto context, or a copy from a compute step, or whatever. But this statement is also specific to submitting for drawing to screen.
